# Application compatible until win10 but not run in windows server versions

Tags: windows, command-line, crash, command-line-arguments, compatibility

a simple command line x86 application with run format:
**app.exe  infile outfile**
not running in windows server (tested in win server 2016 2019)
some Exception codes :  **0xc0000005       0xc00001a5**
but run without any problem in **windows XP until windows 10 x86/x64** systems
test all compatibility wizard options but no result!
**user : admin and full read/write  access**
in other desktop windows when parameter is invalid show help ,
but in windows server even don't show help.
**it's seems that can't access file and problem in file handling or parameter handling**
how can i do to run this app in windows server (**all possible ways**)
thanks advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: one of result in this experience is : DEP (Data Execution Prevention) in server windows OSes different from desktop Windows OSes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**after search about 0xc0000005**
one of reasons is windows system **DEP (Data Execution Prevention)**
when add process in Exception process list , problem is resolved full option path:
**System Properties(Advance System Settings) -> Advanced->Performance Section->Settings->Data Execution Prevention->Turn On for all program and services except... -> Use Add button and Add your desired application**
thanks all